# Can Google Analytics Track Results from Form POST action?

Tags: http, capture, google-analytics

My product search on my website uses HTTP POST to submit the search information. I want to track the search results page, learning what people are searching for and the results that they get. I'm told that I have to switch to using HTTP GET to make that happen.

Is there a way to keep using HTTP POST and still have Google Analytics pick up the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[_trackPageView()](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55597)** is what you want. I use it to make specific urls for various Goals, but it would also work for search results.